# GameObject in class? Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

im in the middle of a Tower Defense - style developing in Unity using C#. 
So, i have an abstract class for the towers that has an int for the range, the rate of fire, etc. 
And then i have a few child classes for the different type of towers. 
Im in the doubt of having an attribute of type GameObject in the tower class, that contains the Tower Game Object itself (for spawning the projectile, move the tower if necesary) or having the class with the attributes and then having a controller that controls the tower class atributes and also controls the game object itself(when need to move it, set active or not, etc).

I wish i made my self clear!
Thanks!

EDIT

Im not sure wich option would be better.

---

Option 1:

```
public abstract class Tower{
       private int health;
       ...
       private GameObject object;

      public HealthDown(){
          if(health >1){ health -= 1;}
          else { object.SetActive(false);}
      }
}
```

---

Option 2:

```
public abstract class Tower{
       private int health;
       ...

       public HealthDown(){
          if(health >1){ health -= 1;}
      }
}
```

And then a script that controlls the tower:

```
public class Controller : MonoBehaviour {

     Tower tower;
     ...
     void Update(){ 
        if(tower.health <= 1){this.gameObject.SetActive(false);}
     }
}
```

---

I wish now its more clear!

Thanks!

Comment: How is `object` different from `gameObject`?

Comment: object is the same as gameObject. In the first option i will be getting object from the constructor of the class Tower. In the second option i will be getting the gameObject from the script the controller that will be attached to the gameObject itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you have different models/materials for each tower and therefore I would parameterize these different attack rates etc via a `MonoBehavior`-derived script (`TowerController.cs`) attached to each prefab:

```
Tower1 prefab:
    Model = tower
    Material = tower1
    Script = TowerController.cs
        attackRate = 10
        projectilePrefab = projectile1

Tower2 prefab:
    Model = tower
    Material = tower2
    Script = TowerController.cs
        attackRate = 20
        projectilePrefab = projectile2
```

This follows normal Unity workflow and allows editing via the UI and to be overridden by instances if required.

Therefore neither Option 1 nor Option 2, but closer to Option 2 without class inheritance, and more Unity-conventional.

Here's an example implementation of `TowerController` allowing the `attackRate` and the projectile prefab to be set (so you can have different versions for each tower type, set via the UI):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TowerController: MonoBehaviour
{
    public int health = 50;
    public int attackRate = 10;
    public GameObject projectilePrefab;

    public void TakeDamage(int damage)
    {
        health -= damage;
        if (health <= 0) {
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    private void FireProjectile()
    {
        GameObject projectile = Instantiate(projectilePrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation) as GameObject;
        projectile.transform.SetParent(transform.parent, true);
        // Add force etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Where that attackRate parameter would be defined? And if i wanted to make a FireProjectile() method, how can i define one method for the different types of towers?

Comment: @FaustoSanchez What are the different behaviours of `FireProjectile()` for each tower type?

Comment: Im sorry, i didnt make my self clear, i need just one method for all the towers. And then could you give me an example on how to use this implementation? Thanks man!

Comment: @FaustoSanchez Updated, in order to give you an idea.

Comment: Im sorry, im new to stackoverflow, i dont know what you mean.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the example implementation you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Tower : MonoBehaviour {
    private int health;
    public int Health
    {
        get { return health; }
        set { SetHealth(value); }
    }
    ...

    public SetHealth(int value){
        health = Math.Max(value, 0);
        gameObject.SetActive(health > 1);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Tower tower1 = GameObject.Find("Tower1").GetComponent<Tower>();

// Attack tower 1
tower1.Health--;
```